# Mathematica -- generate a list of primes up to a limit

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the simplest function that generates a list of primes up to the argument?  Its not hard to come up with such a function, for instance:

```
foo[n_] := Block[{A = {}, p = 2},
           While[p < n, A = Append[A, p]; p = NextPrime[p]];
           A]
```

However, this seems overly messy.  I would like to do something like

```
foo[n_] := Table[Prime[i], {i,2,???}]
```

Where ??? is the index of`NextPrime[n,-1]`.  Is this possible?

Comment: You may be interested to know that there is a [Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). When programming in Mathematica, it is always good to check all uses of `While`, [`For`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/8), `Do` and `Append`. They are hangovers from other languages and (as the answers below show), there are [usually more concise approaches in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/8).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example

```
f[x_] := Prime[Range@PrimePi@x]
```

Usage

```
Grid[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 13, 20}], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. The part I was missing (I called it ???, basically the inverse of `Prime`), was `PrimePi`

Answer (score 3):

My favorite form:

```
p = Prime ~Array~ PrimePi@# &;

p @ 20
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}

Answer (score -1):

One of the common algorithms for this is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  It is a straightforward algorithm and reasonably easy to implement in any language.

Comment: The OP is not asking for an algorithm, but for a specific function in a specific language. Moreover, the language in question have the needed primitives already available. Please look at the tags before answering.